# How do I run grep on a zsh variable?

Tags: grep, scripting, zsh

I'd like to inline the following 2 commands:

```
big_query_that_returns_text > in.txt
$ printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar" | grep -f /dev/stdin in.txt
```

that do work by finding `foo` and `bar` in `in.txt`

but when I try to

```
printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar" | grep -f /dev/stdin big_query_that_returns_text
```

I receive

```
zsh: argument list too long: grep
```

I also tried

```
var=`big_query_that_returns_text`
printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar" | grep -f /dev/stdin $var
printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar" | grep -f /dev/stdin "$var"
```

but I receive the same error.

Comment: Given your error message, your shell is obviously zsh, not bash. I've edited the tag and title to reflect it. You'd get the same behaviour in `bash`, but it's important you specify the right shell so answerers give you code in the right syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a place for a [process substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution): it's a block of code that acts like a file

Pipe the big query results to grep's stdin

```bsh
big_query_that_returns_text | grep -f <(printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar")
```

If the command to produce "foo" and "bar" is more complicated, you can help readability with arbitrary newlines inside the process substitution:

```bsh
big_query_that_returns_text \
| grep -f <(
      printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar"
  )
```

Comment: If the list of regexps is reasonably small, you can also do `big_query_that_returns_text | grep -e "$(printf '%s\n' "foo" "bar")"`

Comment: @glenn: Some people believe that you also help readability by putting the ```|``` at the end of the first line rather than the beginning of the second one.  Then you don’t need the ``\``, and you can put comments at the ends of any and all lines.

Comment: I find putting the pipe (or `||` or `&&` operator) at the end kind of "hides" it. Putting it up front is more visible and that overrides the distaste of using a line continuation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to search for `foo` or `bar` in a zsh variable that basically is the output of some command. I'm not sure why you go the extra way to pipe the search strings to `grep`, but unless this is absolutely required, you could do

```bsh
big_query_that_returns_text | grep -E "foo|bar"
```

If you want to use the output of `big_query_that_returns_text` in more than one place, and for this reason store it in a shell variable, you can still use

```bsh
var=$(big_query_that_returns_text)

printf '%s\n' "$var" | grep -E "foo|bar"

... (other operations on $var) ...
```

Here using `printf '%s\n'`. Other alternatives would be `print -r -- "$var"` or `echo -E - "$var"` or use a here-document or here-string. All of `printf`, `print` and `echo` are built-in in `zsh`, so you won't get the *argument list too long* error which is a limitation of the `execve()` system call, so only applies to external commands that are executed (like `grep` which is not builtin in `zsh`).

Comment: Well, not exactly, my list of foo bars are over 500 which is the reason I receive zsh: argument list too long: grep as far as I can see.

Comment: What I wanna do is to run in a single command:

big_query_that_returns_over_1000_words | grep -f /dev/stdin big_query_that_returns_text

Comment: @SergeVu Interesting. I would have thought that if the argument list is too long for `grep`, it would also be for `printf`.

Comment: @SergeVu I see you edited your comment. So the `printf` is only a placeholder, and in reality you call an external command that generates the search words? If so, it would be good to have that included in the question ...